# postgresql ignore index after vacuum

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, database-indexes, vacuum

I have the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX in_table_1
  ON table_1
  USING btree
  ((COALESCE(col_1, 30001231::bigint)), col_2);
```

and the following select

```
select * from tabela_1
where coalesce(col_1, 30001231) >= 20150630 and col_1 <= 20150630
```

Im having a performance problem, I checked and my select is not using the index I created.

If I drop and recreate the index, my select uses it.

I noticed that after running a vacuum on the table, the problem starts again.

The vacuum is doing something that makes the database stop using the index?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: A functional index on COALESCE() makes little sense to mee. Why not a conditional index on `col_1 IS NOT NULL) (makes little sense either) and/or one on `col_1 IS NULL` ?